# Install xConnect Separately with Sitecore upgrade

Tags: xconnect, upgrade

I am looking to install `xConnect` only through SIF with 9.1.1. I am upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 so didn't had any preexisting `xConnect` setup.

Following the upgrade process from Sitecore which says that you have to install `xConnect` only but I am not able to find the process for that in the guide. I know that I can use SIF to install `xConnect` only but not sure what sort of configuration I need.

I can use the `singledeveloper.ps1` script to install everything and remove the not required components afterwards as an alternative. Has anyone encountered into similar situation before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommends you create a new environment and migrate your data/site into that environment. With 9.1 beyond xConnect you have identity server all all the configs that tie it together.

This file will set up all the parameters for xconnect install. Just change the name and paths to what you need.

#### Install-Xconnect-tasks-parameters.ps1

```
#define parameters
$prefix = "sc91"
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\resourcefiles"

$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect"
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc"
$SolrUrl = "https://solr:8983/solr"
$SolrRoot = "C:\solr\solr-7.2.1"
$SolrService = "Solr-7.2.1"
$SqlServer = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
$SqlAdminUser = "dev"
$SqlAdminPassword = "dev123"
$IdentityServerSiteName = "$prefix.identityserver"
$ClientSecret="Random_STRING"
$SitecoreAdminPassword = "b"


#install client certificate for xconnect
$certParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\createcert.json"
 CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client"
}

#install solr cores for xdb
$XconnectsolrParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"
 SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
 SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
 SolrService = $SolrService
 CorePrefix = $prefix
}

#deploy xconnect instance
$xconnectParams = @{
 Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"
 Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. 001564 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
 LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
 Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService
 XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
 SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
 SqlServer = $SqlServer
 SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
 SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
 SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
 SolrURL = $SolrUrl
}
```

This file kicks off the parameters you specified above.

### Install Script

```
. $PSScriptRoot\Install-Xconnect-tasks-parameters.ps1

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @XconnectsolrParams

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have already installed identity server and it is working.